# Parallels plesk permissions accessing through FTP

Tags: permissions, centos, plesk, parallels, centos6

Our server is running under CentOS 6 and handled over Panel Plesk 10.4.4. Structure of folders and files is created using php script. Then, when accessing through FTP we are unable to modify these folder contents previously created. When accessing it over Apache web user works without exception but not over ftp. Folders and files have 755 and 644 rights respectively. How to enable ftp acces? Thank you

EDIT: problem is that file owner and ftp are not the same but I do not know exactly how and where to attach it.
File and folders owner is psacln (gid 502) and group is apache (gid 503). Ftp users are not the same.

We add a login ftp user (also system one) to the group owner of files and folders "psacln" using `usermod -a -G psacln ftpusername`. Same procedure with apache group but problem persists.

Comment: what is your file owner and group and ftp login? ftp login equal with file owner?

Comment: not the same, I edit my question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here would be that you probably run your site in mod_php mode. In this mode scripts are operated under Apache privileges, so all files and directories created are owned by Apache. This way the files cannot be accessed by your FTP user unless you set up 777 or 666 permissions.

I think your options could be

1. switch to FastCGI mode of PHP. Depending on your Plesk account privileges, you can either do it yourself in Plesk UI or will have to ask hosting provider for that. 
   This way your script will be operated under user privileges (same as FTP user) and there will be no problems with  accessing these files through FTP. Also this option is often considered more secure.
2. make PHP script setting 777 permissions on your folders and 666 permissions on your files. It means you allow to modify them by everyone (so called "others"). So FTP user can modify these files as well. While this may sound insecure, but practically these files are already can be accessed from any other site on that system (if it is shared hosting server). So I don't think it will be any more insecure than the current status.

Regards

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Point 2 is not a proper solution for us due to any other reasons. However, point 1 could be done! Problem is that have different PHP execution mode and some functions doesn't work. For example when trying to authenticate an user, session variable is not recognized. Can be solved easily? If not we have a lot of code to modify and not a solution :(

Comment: Perhaps http://kb.parallels.com/7056 can help. I think there was similar problem in earlier versions, but it says it is fixed in 10.4...

Comment: finally! we just get it running! bounty ended, is there any way for you to get 50+? I aprreciate so much your help!